# how to catch uncaught exception (globally) in react native

Tags: react-native

Does anyone know what is the best way to catch all uncaught exception (globally) so that I can send a crash report back to the server? I don't seem to be able to find any information on the react native docs or on github.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this, exactly?

Answer (score 32):

You could possibly override the exception logging that React Native uses for development:

```
ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(function() {
// your handler here
});
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/522fd33d6f3c8fb339b0dde35b05df34c1233306/Libraries/JavaScriptAppEngine/Initialization/InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js#L46

You may then need to write some Obj-C which you expose to JS, depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 14):

This is how I'd do it:

**Step 1:** We intercept react-native error handler like so:

```
//intercept react-native error handling
if (ErrorUtils._globalHandler) {
  this.defaultHandler = ErrorUtils.getGlobalHandler && ErrorUtils.getGlobalHandler() || ErrorUtils._globalHandler;
  ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(this.wrapGlobalHandler);  //feed errors directly to our wrapGlobalHandler function
}
```

**Step 2:** Now our `wrapGlobalHandler` gets called whenever theres an unhandled error. So do anything you want with the error within this function.

Then do something with the error:

```
async function wrapGlobalHandler(error, isFatal){

    const stack = parseErrorStack(error);

    //do anything with the error here

    this.defaultHandler(error, isFatal);  //after you're finished, call the defaultHandler so that react-native also gets the error
}
```

Full code here:

```
import stacktraceParser from 'stacktrace-parser';


const parseErrorStack = (error) => {
    if (!error || !error.stack) {
        return [];
    }
    return Array.isArray(error.stack) ? error.stack :
    stacktraceParser.parse(error.stack);
};


// intercept react-native error handling
if (ErrorUtils._globalHandler) {
    this.defaultHandler = (ErrorUtils.getGlobalHandler
        && ErrorUtils.getGlobalHandler())
        || ErrorUtils._globalHandler;
    ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(this.wrapGlobalHandler); // feed errors directly to our wrapGlobalHandler function
}

async function wrapGlobalHandler(error, isFatal) {

    const stack = parseErrorStack(error);

    //do anything with the error here

    this.defaultHandler(error, isFatal);  //after you're finished, call the defaultHandler so that react-native also gets the error
}
```

Thats it!

Comment: May I ask what is parseErrorStack function supposed to do? when I try to log the error param on chrome I get some output, but on react-native I only get an empty object

Comment: Hey ospfranco, I just added the full code, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @SudoPlz could you please explain where should I use this code?

Comment: @Ansal Ali you can use it anywhere on your code, and it should work.
Ideally I'd use it on the initialization file of the app. (Before the first component loads).

Comment: @Ansal Ali take a look at this file:
https://github.com/SudoPlz/react-native-bugsnag/blob/master/lib/RNBugsnag.js

It might help you understand what you're doing differently.
I was using that code for a long time and it worked fine.

Comment: @SudoPlz Can you provide example how to call from app initialization?

Comment: Sorry I can't do that, but this should give you ALL you need:
https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native/blob/333c9714b7c777a5f8b82062658c44018196aeef/src/Bugsnag.js#L43:L59

After that just calling `this.handleUncaughtErrors();` should be enough.

Comment: Does this catch errors produced by native modules too or just JS errors?

Answer (score 6):

You can try https://github.com/master-atul/react-native-exception-handler.

A react native module that lets you to register a global error handler that can capture fatal/non fatal uncaught exceptions. The module helps prevent abrupt crashing of RN Apps without a graceful message to the user.

Answer (score 4):

There is a native way.

```
RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:_scriptURL
                                      moduleProvider:^{
                                        id<RCTExceptionsManagerDelegate> customDelegate = ...
                                        return @[[RCTExceptionsManager initWithDelegate:customDelegate];
                                      }
                                       launchOptions:nil];
```

Just put your report logic in the `customDelegate`.

Comment: If you had the respective solution for Android that would turn out super helpful for me.

Comment: @jeevium you can use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` in Android

Answer (score 3):

There's now [react-native-error-reporter](https://github.com/VansonLeung/react-native-error-reporter), which pretty much does the trick in a very simple way:

```
npm i react-native-error-reporter --save
rnpm link
```

Then add this lines to your code:

```
import ErrorReporter from 'react-native-error-reporter';
ErrorReporter.init("vanson@vanportdev.com", "My App's Crash Report");
```

In case you're using Redux, you might wanna try [redux-catch](https://github.com/sergiodxa/redux-catch) middleware.

Comment: Better than `react-native-error-reporter` there's now `react-native-exception-handler` which gives you an interface to the user AND a way to catch native errors.

https://github.com/master-atul/react-native-exception-handler