# App crashes when clicked on "copy" option from context menu of selected text in android webview on many devices

Tags: android, android-webview, react-native, android-contextmenu

I think this is the main reason why it crashes, I've also added full crash log below.

```
Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 in tid 9877 (mqt_native_modu), pid 9829 (com.example.app)
```

Here is the link to full crash log:

https://pastebin.com/QxrFynHw

Comment: There might be [useful tools described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947752/whats-a-good-setup-for-react-native-crash-reporting)?