# How to handle Exception and show Alert when network request fails due to timeout on React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want my app to show an [Alert](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html) to the user when an API request fails, for example when the backend server has gone down. The alert would notify the user that the request has failed and allow the user to retry the request or to return to the main dashboard screen via `navigator.resetTo('dashboard')`.

Is there a way to globally catch a network failed exception so that I don't have to wrap each call to the API in a separate try/catch block?

E.g.

```
await backend.getUser(); //throws TimeoutException

//TimeoutException should be globally caught and show the Alert to user

/* somewhere else in the app */

await backend.uploadImage(image); //throws TimeoutException
```

I can see how I could catch errors globally using the [answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918349/how-to-catch-uncaught-exception-globally-in-react-native):

```
ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(function() {
// your handler here
});
```

However, how would I be able to pass my [`navigator`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) to the error handler, so that I can change the scene to redirect the user back to the dashboard for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to catch uncaught exception (globally) in react native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918349/how-to-catch-uncaught-exception-globally-in-react-native)