# How to report different errors in React Native application?

Tags: error-handling, exception, react-native, crash-reports

Is there a solution for reporting different errors in React Native application (iOS and Android) as a global handler?

I am interested in following cases:

1. Unhandled rejections
2. Unhandled exceptions
3. Errors on the native side

By reporting, I mean sending them to some third-party service where you can track errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918349/how-to-catch-uncaught-exception-globally-in-react-native

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to catch uncaught exception (globally) in react native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918349/how-to-catch-uncaught-exception-globally-in-react-native)

Answer (score 3):

In RN there is a ErrorUtils global handler, that handle uncaught and caught exceptions for your RN JS layer. You can use this to set a handler like:

```
if (ErrorUtils._globalHandler) {
            instance.defaultHandler = ErrorUtils.getGlobalHandler && ErrorUtils.getGlobalHandler() || ErrorUtils._globalHandler;
            ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(instance.wrapGlobalHandler);  //feed errors directly to our wrapGlobalHandler function
        }
```

And handler method

```
async wrapGlobalHandler(error, isFatal){

      const stack = parseErrorStack(error);

     //Add this error locally or send it your remote server here

      //*> Finish activity
      setTimeout (() => {
        instance.defaultHandler(error, isFatal);  //after you're finished, call the defaultHandler so that react-native also gets the error
        if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
          NodeModule.reload()
        }
      }, 1000);
  }
```

Notice in above code you need to create a node module for android only and write a React Native bridge method there in your ReactContextBaseJavaModule:

```
@ReactMethod
    public void reload() {
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivityInstance();
        Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please update your response to use ErrorUtils.setGlobalHeader. It appears that it is now the way to go.

Comment: You can use it in any JS component of your top hierarchy of JS components